# Meaning of this matrix structure

Tags: matrices

A professor is keep using the following kind of matrix. The problem is that I have never seen a matrix separated with these lines inside it. What does that kind of matrix mean (not the contents but the structure)?

[image]

This kind of matrix was used for rotational transformations. The 3x3 matrix is a rotation matrix (the contents in the image are picked just to fill the matrix they are not the ones used by the professor). The other contents I don't know what they were used for. That is one other reason I want to know what this matrix is as to find out more about the other contents.

Comment: Can you provide somewhat more context? Those partitions lines can have different meanings depending on the context, but generally you can say that they were put there to emphasize a certain structure of the matrix.

Comment: Ok I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is structured into *blocks*. The zeroes in non-diagonal blocks are related to some stability property.

Consider a matrix of the form
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e & f \\ 0 & 0 & g & h \end{pmatrix} $$
and assume it is associated to some linear map $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to the canonical basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4)$.

The lower-left block of zeroes means that $\varphi(e_1)$ and $\varphi(e_2)$ belong to the vector susbspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$. Thus that subspace is stable under $\varphi$.

Likewise the subspace spanned by $e_3$ and $e_4$ is stable under $\varphi$ as the upper-right block of zeroes suggests.